# Gitlab 404 on Files an Commit Pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, osx-mountain-lion, gitlab

I finally got Gitlab running on Mountain Lion Server.

Everything seems to work fine except the Files and Commit Pages, I always get "404
The resource you were looking for doesn't exist."

But the Repository is there and not empty, I can push and pull it with Git Tower without problems.

And another strange behavior is that the Network Tab works like a charm.

bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production looks also fine

```
Checking Environment ...

gitlab user is in gitg group? ... yes
Has no "-e" in ~gitolite/.profile ... yes
Git configured for gitlab user? ... yes
Has python2? ... yes
python2 is supported version? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking Gitolite ...

Using recommended version ... no
  Try fixing it:
  We strongly recommend using the version pointed out in the installation guide.
  For more information see:
  doc/install/installation.md in section "Gitolite"
Repo umask is 0007 in .gitolite.rc? ... yes
Allow all Git config keys in .gitolite.rc ... yes
Config directory exists? ... yes
Config directory owned by gitolite:gitg ... yes
Config directory access is drwxr-x---? ... yes
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by gitolite:gitg? ... yes
Repo base access is drwsrws---? ... yes
Can clone gitolite-admin? ... yes
Can commit to gitolite-admin? ... yes
post-receive hook exists? ... yes
post-receive hook up-to-date? ... yes
post-receive hooks in repos are links: ... 
Groz Beckert Company Presentation Standalone App ... ok
Git config in repos: ... 
Groz Beckert Company Presentation Standalone App ... ok

Checking Gitolite ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... no
  Try fixing it:
  Install the init script
  For more information see:
  doc/install/installation.md in section "Install Init Script"
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.
Init script up-to-date? ... can't check because of previous errors
Projects have satellites? ... 
Groz Beckert Company Presentation Standalone App ... yes

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

Anyone got a clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may depend on which exact version of GitLab you are running:

[Issue 2698](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/2698), solved a mere 20 days ago by [Issue 2602](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/2602), seems to indicate an issue when using gitlab in a subdomain, with relative address links:

```
 http://dev.mysite.com:81/gitlab/
```

Comment: Thanks again for the hint!

I thought it would be enough to define RailsBaseURI in my Apache conf, but as it turned out I had to add `ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT']` to my config/environments/production.conf and uncomment `relative_url_root:` in config/gitlab.yml